# PHP MySQL login function

Tags: php, mysql, function, authentication

I'm using this:

```
function authUser($username, $password){
    connectDB();
    $sql = "SELECT id, username FROM users where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_rows > 0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $username = $row['username'];
            session_start(); 
            session_register('username');
        return $username; 
        }
    }
    closeConn();
}
```

With a combination of this:

```
$auth = authUser($username, $password);
if (isset($username)){
    header( "Location: index.php" );
}
```

And then on the index.php (where i redirect them if a successful login) i'm trying to echo $username. But nothing is showing? Any ideas? Is this function the problem?

EDIT:

have now changed it so:

```
if ($num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
      return true; 
    }
}
```

Is that right?

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plain text in the database.  Every time you do that, a cute little kitten dies.

Comment: I'm getting basic functionality then i'm going to use md5...kitten saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
  return true; 
}
```

into:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
```

because you want to login and get ONE person out

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you are always re-directing to `index.php`, not only on a successful login;

```
$auth = authUser($username, $password);
if (isset($username)){
    header( "Location: index.php" );
}
```

`$username` is set, both on a successful and a non-successful login.

Comment: @benhowdle89, I don´t know if you still have a problem, but you need to start every page with `session_start()` before anything is outputted to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First, session_register is deprecated. use $_SESSION:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
```

Second, your authUser() function returns either a username (if successful) or nothing. Then this code:

```
$auth = authUser($username, $password);
if (isset($username))...
```

should be changed to

```
$username = authUser($username, $password);
if (isset($username))...
```

And one more thing, checking for passwords in the clear is a very very bad thing :) Consider hashing it with MD5().

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `session_start()` on the index page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure index.php has a `session_start()` called at the top of the script, and also, try using `$_SESSION['username']` instead of just `$username`.  A lot of servers nowadays are set up so you have to call the full variable (with $_SESSION) rather than just the shortened version.  Read about Register Globals at http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php.  If you still have problems, take the `session_start()` out of the authUser function and move it to the first line of that script as well.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not global between page instances, you need to put the variable in $_SESSION if you want it to be accessible over multiple pages.

Answer (score -2):

If you use `mysql_fetch_array` then you should use array, like this: `$row[0]`

You can use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to use table column name (`$row['username']`)

Comment: mysql_fetch_array has a 2nd parameter to allow index access via column name

Comment: -1 Late answer review:  This answer is factually incorrect. As specified by @RichardTheKiwi, one can use either `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` or `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)` to return an associative array indexes (based on column names) - and the default is `MYSQL_BOTH` anyway, so the OP's use of the function is fine. Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php